# Webhook URL - Facebook integration of an IBM Watson app

Tags: facebook, ibm-cloud, chatbot, messenger, watson-conversation

I'm a beginner in IBM environment. I'm working on a Watson Conversation chatbot developed in the IBM Bluemix environment. My IBM app is synchronized with a Github repository through the IBM toolchain service. My app and my chatbot work in the web page given by Bluemix.

But, when it comes to integrating my bot to Facebook messenger, I'm stuck with the Webhook thing. I have no idea which URL I should fill in and where this URL must point.

BTW my env variables are set (MESSENGER_PAGE_TOKEN, MESSENGER_APP_SECRET, MESSENGER_VERIFY_TOKEN, MESSENGER_WEBHOOKENDPOINT). The last 2 are not generated; I've set them myself.

If anyone could help me to create/find the webhook URL, it would be really nice as I'm so lost.

Comment: I am not an expert in this area. However, the information on this page might point you in the right direction: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks

Comment: Have you been able to figure it out? I am using a Watson Conversation bot together with Botkit, and couldn't find out what webhook URL I should use.

Comment: Found it deep in the docs! `By default Botkit will serve content from "https://YOURSERVER/facebook/receive". `

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a call back URL(which will be your Bluemix app that has chatbot) at first and then update it in the Webhook URL input

You can refer these:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/quick-start

https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/.../bot-for-facebook-messenger-using-bluemix/